# Как сделать, чтобы webstorm смотрел на babel config?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, babel, alias

Как сделать, чтобы webstorm смотрел на babel config? Нужно из babel вытянуть alias, чтобы при импорте файлов можно было через Ctrl переходить в файл.
Без использования webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за пакет вы используете? [babel-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-resolver), [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias) или еще какой-то? Проблема в том, что таких пакетов - множество, у каждого свой синтаксис, и поддержать их все нет ну никакой физической возможности. Поэтому ответ - никак.

В качестве workaround могу предложить создать в корне проекта файл `config.js` (может быть любое другое имя) и определить там ваши alias-ы в формате

```
System.config({
      "paths": {
         "alias/*": "./aliased/dir/*"
      }
    });
```

понятно, что вместо `alias/*` нужно подставить реальный alias из  babel config, вместо `./aliased/dir/*` - соответствующий путь.

В следующей версии мы также планируем поддержать path mappings в [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Comment: Благодарю. Использую babel-resolver, сделаю как вы описали, надеюсь всё получится.